# Redirect HTTP traffic to an internal Web Server for a particular subdomain

Tags: iis, redirect, tomcat6, forwarding

I can't get my head around the following situation. We have an outside-available web site (say, `http://example.com`). It runs on our Windows 2008 server in IIS7. Now I want to make one of our internal servers available to the outside world as well (`http://dev.example.com`). I've set up DNS entries so that `dev.example.com` points to the same IP as `example.com` does, but I'm not sure how to configure web servers correctly.

This `dev` server hosts, among other things, an [OpenID](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CROWD/CrowdID+User+Guide) server (which, I think, can cause some serious problems when web servers are incorrectly configured), bug tracker and a Subversion repository. This whole slew of applications runs inside Tomcat 6 which is, to my limted knowledge, is not a web server per se. I know that it can talk to Apache and I'll install it if it's really needed.

The question is: how do I set up IIS/Tomcat/DNS/whatever so that the configuration I just described will work seamlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deal is as follows. First, a DNS record for `dev.example.com` is required. It should point (in my case) to the same IP as `example.com` does. Next, install Tomcat Connector as described [here](http://www.iisadmin.co.uk/?p=72) and you'll be all fine and dandy.

Answer (score 2):

What you really need is to reverse proxy to your tomcat server.  As far as I'm aware, it's a plugin that you need to install for IIS (see http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/urlrewriter)

FYI, had your external web-server been Apache, the feature is built in and EASILY configured.

Also, Tomcat does work as a web-server (how else would it serve web pages?), so you wont need to install Apache on your internal systems.

Answer (score 0):

Use Host headers, put the host header dev.example.com in for the dev website. DNS points traffic to the IIS (IP address/Port 80) and then IIS points the traffic to the subdomain.